# Improving a MongoDB LINQ expression to avoid for each loop

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am querying a mongodb collection through the C# driver, but have been unable to come up with the LINQ expression that can remove Items based on restriction by SubCategory per Category.  In the below test, if the Item is in Category 22 and the Item is also in SubCategory A or B, then the Item shouldn't be returned from the query.

The test passes as it is currently written, but I feel there is a better way to do this without using the foreach loop.  Any ideas?

```
[Test]
public void RemoveItemsBasedOnCategorySubCategoryRestrictions()
{
    var restrictionsByCategorySubCategories = new Dictionary<String, List<String>> {
        { "22", new List<String> { "A", "B" } },
        { "32", new List<String> { "A" } }
    };

    var items = new List<Item> { 
        new Item { Category = "32", SubCategory = new List<String> { "Z" } },
        new Item { Category = "32", SubCategory = new List<String> { "A" } }, 
        new Item { Category = "22", SubCategory = new List<String> { "Z" } },
        new Item { Category = "22", SubCategory = new List<String> { "A" } },
        new Item { Category = "22", SubCategory = new List<String> { "B" } } 
    }.AsQueryable();

    var results = new List<Item>();

    foreach (var restrictionsByCategorySubCategory in restrictionsByCategorySubCategories)
    {
        var category = restrictionsByCategorySubCategory.Key;
        var subCategories = restrictionsByCategorySubCategory.Value;

        results.AddRange(items.Where(p => p.Category.Equals(category) && !p.SubCategory.ContainsAny(subCategories)));
    }

    Assert.That(results.ToList(), Has.Count.EqualTo(2));

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Assert.That(result.SubCategory, Is.Not.EqualTo("A"));
        Assert.That(result.SubCategory, Is.Not.EqualTo("B"));
    }
}
```

Item:

```
class Item
{
    public String Category;
    public List<String> SubCategory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll use `restrictions` dictionary name instead of `restrictionsByCategorySubCategories`  for making code more compact:

```
var results =  items.Where(i =>
     !restrictions.ContainsKey(i.Category) ||
     !restrictions[i.Category].Intersect(i.SubCategory).Any());
```

Or query syntax:

```
var results = 
   from i in items
   where !restrictions.ContainsKey(i.Category) ||              
         !restrictions[i.Category].Intersect(i.SubCategory).Any()
   select i;
```

Logic is pretty straight-forward - you get items which don't have their category in restricted list, or which don't have any sub-category in restricted category sub-categories.

Results:

```
[
  { Category: "32", SubCategory: [ "Z" ] },
  { Category: "22", SubCategory: [ "Z" ] }
]
```

Don't know if Linq to MongoDb can translate this query, but your code does not have any Linq to MongoDb - its simply Linq to Objects.

Comment: Thanks...but as you suspected, the MongoDB driver cannot translate it.

Comment: @jsmorris then I have doubts about possibility to do this with single Linq to MongoDb query. Btw as I already mentioned you have Linq to Objects queries. Where is MongoDb?